# Runtime exception Unable to pre-dex

Tags: android, android-studio, exception

Have got an error as seen in log below

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex 'C:\Users\xxxx\.android\build-cache\8a8f5dc798b45b1d3ff133df3988ae430f7e4158\output\jars\classes.jar' to 'F:\yyyyy\happy \app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\classes_88e225087cead8e4043cef843dd9c6adee64176a'
```

Have tried below steps but did not worked as such :

1: multiDexEnabled = true.
2: Clean and Rebuild.
3: Restart Android studio and Laptop also.

Comment: do you have this code in build.gradle? ```androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })```